# I need help using Jsoup to display the html from a website

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

very new to coding, using Java writing android application.   I have included my code to this point below.  At this point I am just trying to get the HTML from a website.  I have been googling my way to this point.  I do have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`in the manifest. I call the code to get the html in the oncreate event (new URLParser). At first I tried to view the html in the logcat, the code is still there for that in the onPostExecute event.  The program ran fine this way, but the html did not show up in the verbose section of the logcat.  So I added a temporary button and text view to the application.  The button's onClick is set to call "showHTML".  The app loads up, and when I press the button it crashes.  So I cannot seem to see the html in the logcat, or the textview after pressing the button.

```
package com.example.brewerycruiser;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            new URLParser();

        }

        public void showHTML (View view) {
            TextView HTMLview =
                    view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.textView);
            HTMLview.setText(doc.toString());

        }

        Document doc = null;

        public class URLParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


                try {
                    doc =  Jsoup.connect("https://www.coloradobrewerylist.com/brewery/").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();


                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }


                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                Log.v("DATA", doc.toString());

            }

        }

    }
```

The error log is below:

```
11-19 18:09:32.779 18293-18293/com.example.brewerycruiser E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.brewerycruiser, PID: 18293
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5225)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21195)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5225) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21195) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.jsoup.nodes.Document.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.brewerycruiser.MainActivity.showHTML(MainActivity.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5225) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21195) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, 
Thank you

Comment: `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.jsoup.nodes.Document.toString()' on a null object reference` says it all. `doc` is null. For further help you'll have to tell us the url your trying to scrape.

Comment: https://www.coloradobrewerylist.com/brewery/ is the url

Comment: 1. I ran the `get` and `toString` commands as "pure java" (i.e. using eclipse ide, not as an android app) and it works fine for me. 2. You have a typo in your code - `//http` - the slashes are redundent - I hope that it is just in the question. 3. Can you see the page in your browser? Maybe it's a firewall releated problem or something similar.

Comment: Page loads fine in my browser including on android...// was typo, program code does not have it

Comment: When do you call `showHTML`? Looks like it is being called before you fetch the document.

Comment: I call `showHTML` on a button press after the app loads.  But I call new `URLParser` in the OnCreate event. When I call `URLParser` perhaps I need to give it more time to finish getting the html before pressing button?  I can try this later, when I have access to my PC.  There is a table that takes a little time to populate on that URL(which is the information I'm after).  Could this cause a problem?

Comment: Are you sure that URLParser executes? You have to launch it with `execute()`. Add some log prints in your code and see what gets executes and what does not.

Comment: That did it, i added the .execute() and I am now getting the HTML.  Thank you for your help.